# Python's exec running in module works but in function not

Tags: python-3.x, function, module, exec

This works:

```
import os
import sys
with open('tests.py') as fptr:
    script_content = fptr.read()
exec(script_content)
```

And this not:

```
def run():
    import os
    import sys
    with open('tests.py') as fptr:
        script_content = fptr.read()
    exec(script_content)

run()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 8, in <module>
    run()
  File "tmp.py", line 6, in run
    exec(script_content)
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 16, in PlaceSpitter
NameError: name 'Place' is not defined
```

Could anyone tell my why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I've read again - carrefully - [python's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) especially this one:

> Remember that at module level, globals and locals are the same dictionary

And try this:

```
def run():
    import os
    import sys
    with open('tests.py') as fptr:
        script_content = fptr.read()
    exec(script_content, globals())

run()
```

which now works!

I still don't know why but now at least it works.